# Too few values in struct intializer error

Tags: go

i am getting the error, too few values in struct initialiser at line  clusters = append(clusters, Cluster{Point{rand.Float64()}, []Point{}}) 
the function that throws the error is below.

```
func initClusters(k int) (clusters []Cluster) {
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
for i := 0; i < k; i++ {
    clusters = append(clusters, Cluster{Point{rand.Float64()},[]Point{}})
}
return
}
```

i am putting k = 3,  the cluster struct defined is

```
type Cluster struct {
Center Point
Points []Point
}
```

and the point is also a struct defined as:

```
type Point struct {
X float64
Y float64
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

A struct composite literal must either use named fields or specify all fields. The Point struct has two fields, X and Y.  Assuming that you were attempting to set the X field, do one of the following:

```
 Point{X: rand.Float64()}  // Y defaults to zero value
 Point(X: rand.Float64(), Y: 0} // Y explicitly set to zero using name
 Point(rand.Float64(), 0}  // Y explicitly set to zero using positional value
```

Specifying struct fields by name is generally preferred over positional values.

Comment: i tried that and it did solve it for a moment but it is now giving this,&{44 0 0 true false false false 0xc4200c4000 0 [] [] [] []} ?

Comment: Edit the question to show what is producing that output and a description of what you expect.  Note that the output in your comment shows boolean values, yet the question does use any boolean types. It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: it is showing that because of the 0 y values, but i want to run through a dataset and assign first value to a slice named x and second column to a slice named y, and then append them to a single file called dataset??                                              for {
       record, err := reader.Read()
      for _, i := range record[:1] {
        parsedValue, err := strconv.ParseFloat(i, 64)
            dataset = append(dataset, gomeans.Point{parsedValue,0}) }, like here i am i want to iterate through record and get x and y value?(ist and 2nd field respectively)?

Comment: Your first comment states that the problem is solved. You then go on to describe issues not supported by the question. As already noted, there are no booleans in the question. There are no slices or columns named x and y in the question. I suggest asking a new question about these other problems.  Include minimal code illustrating the problem in that question.

Comment: this is a new issue but they blocked me becoz someone downvoted my question, i dont know..my question was pretty clear and neat to me...

Comment: Your comments here make it unclear what you are asking.  The question also shows lack of research.